# ctypes string buffer in scope

Tags: python, ctypes

thank you for your time reading this, this bugs me long time.I'm using Python3.8 and using `ctypes` to call a DLL. In most of cases ,`ctypes` works like charm.

One function from C DLL will output a list of names  i.e

```
int get_date(char* names[]) // each name has length 10, with size of 5
```

in Python I'm successfully call it like

```py
    string_buffers = [ctypes.create_string_buffer(10) for i in range(5)]
    char_array = (ctypes.c_char_p*5)(*map(ctypes.addressof, string_buffers))
    handler.get_date(char_array)
```

But I am try to factor out a function to create such case :

```py
def create_char_p_array(length:int, size:int):
    string_buffers = [create_string_buffer(length) for i in range(size)]
    ia = (c_char_p*size)(*map(addressof, string_buffers))
    return ia

char_array = create_char_p_array(10,5)
handler.get_date(char_array) ### failed, or ,crashed, or random value ###
```

So to narrow down the issue, I move out the map(addressof) out, it magically works! :

```py
def create_char_p_array(length:int, size:int):
    string_buffers = [create_string_buffer(length) for i in range(size)]
    return string_buffers

sbrs = create_char_p_array(10,5)
char_array = (c_char_p*5)(*map(addressof, sbrs ))
handler.get_date(char_array) # Success !
```

Is it because `create_string_buffer` created in function scope will be wipe out once the function `create_char_p_array` return ?

Thank you for your time ,much appreciated.

Comment: Scope isn't the issue - reachability is. The array objects have to be reachable through a chain of Python references, or they become eligible for reclamation, and a ctypes pointer doesn't count as a Python reference.

Comment: So you get an error without initializing the strings?

Comment: @CristiFati , I tried with c_char_p(" " * size) ,but failed as well . i guess this is serving purpose of initialized a string

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thank you for your reply. Any chances that I can factor out this ? then I don't have to `(c_char_p*5)(*map(addressof, sbrs ))` every time

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ctypes pointers do create references but in this case the object was an integer (the address). See my answer with cast.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Apparently the pointer object does keep a reference if you go through something like `ctypes.cast`. They can't always do that, though - information about what object to keep a reference to isn't always available for all methods of constructing a pointer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  `addressof` doesn't create a reference to the object it operates on.  `cast` will.

test.c:

```
#include <string.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int get_date(char* names[])
{
    strcpy_s(names[0],10,"One");
    strcpy_s(names[1],10,"Two");
    strcpy_s(names[2],10,"Three");
    strcpy_s(names[3],10,"Four");
    strcpy_s(names[4],10,"Five");
    return 5;
}
```

test.py:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./x')
dll.get_date.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),
dll.get_date.restype = c_int

def create_char_p_array(length:int, size:int):
    return (c_char_p*size)(*[cast(create_string_buffer(length),c_char_p) for _ in range(size)])

a = create_char_p_array(10,5)
dll.get_date(a)
for s in a:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
b'One'
b'Two'
b'Three'
b'Four'
b'Five'
```